# 403 error on a PHP page when posting data containing overflow:hidden

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

This is weird - I have a .php file that is taking a POST request.

For some reason the request fails with 403 forbidden:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /
on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

This ONLY happens when the POST request contains the string `overflow:hidden` anywhere in the query string or the POST data.

This must be some kind of security feature on the host. My local WAMP server does not give any such error.

I don't see much in that directory - the php.ini just contains something with magic_quotes turned off, and the .htaccess file in that directory has a couple IP addresses being blocked.

Where do I look next?

Why would anyone ever block just that CSS style? I tried a bunch of other styles like position:fixed or overflow:scroll etc. etc. and only `overflow:hidden` gives the 403.

The host is some cPanel provider, I don't know much about it.

***EDIT:***

I have received several comments to post some code.

index.php contains

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="test" value="overflow:hidden">
  <input type="submit" value="post">
</form>
```

Click the "post" button and it will submit a POST request with the value "overflow:hidden" it doesn't matter if this is a POST or GET. The resulting page will be a 403.

However, I do not even need any code at all - I could just simply hit any page at all and simply add the "overflow:hidden" as a query string parameter like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/somepage.php?test=overflow%3Ahidden
```

Any such request is giving 403. Also - through testing I have found several other phrases that are not allowed, so far I have come across at least 4 different words or phrases that always result in 403.

The PHP is a chat room site, and random people will often complain that their message cannot send.

I have used this exact same code on a different host and there was no issues at all. I am certain that it is this specific host, but I am not sure where this list of banned phrases can be found, or if it can be modified.

Comment: Look into the webservers `error.log` and for mod_security.

Comment: Are you running on a framework?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using?

Comment: the .php code could be empty - all that matters is the HTTP request contains any string with `overflow:hidden` in the data - all such requests return 403.

Comment: Yeah, probably some security thing in between you and the host. mod_security, suhosin, maybe some kind of filtering proxy -- last time I saw something like that, I thought jsfiddle was broken, but it turned out that the corporate firewall I was behind was filtering POSTs with certain Javascript fragments. You may need to do some initial digging to see exactly where the filtering's going on, if there's nothing obvious in the server error log. (Have you tried sending the same POST to a completely different host, just for sanity checking?) Also, let's see minimal code to reproduce, please.